# Parametrizing Rust trait on list of types?

Tags: rust, metaprogramming, traits

I'm toying with an idea for a computation-graph based game engine. The gist is that each abstract concept (Player, Map, Enemy, Spaceship, etc) is a node in a DAG. The nodes themselves are simply Rust types which implement a "Component" interface which specifies how

a. How members of the Component are created/deleted/retrieved

b. What other Components the Component relies on (ie, what are the dependencies?)

c. How to update a member of the Component

Expressing (a) is easy enough: here's a trait which (I think :) specifies this behavior

```
pub trait Component {
    type KeyType: Copy; // Each member of a Component is associated with a key

    fn Add(_: Self::KeyType) -> bool;
    fn Delete(_: Self::KeyType) -> bool;
    fn Get<'a>(_: Self::KeyType) -> Option<&'a Self>;
    fn GetAll<'a>() -> dyn Iterator<Item = (Self::KeyType, &'a Self)>;

    // TODO This block will be described next
}
```

An implementation is easy to imagine: an impl corresponding to the `Player` Component could just use player IDs (`u32`, for instance) for `keys`, and then basically implement all the other functions using some static(global) hash map. So far so good.

---

(b) and (c) are harder. I'd like to express through the trait

1. A `Component` can "rely" on (members of) other `Component`s
2. A member of a `Component` can specify which members of its dependencies that it requires to update itself.
3. Each member of a `Component` implements a function using the results of (2) to update itself.

In other words, I want the `TODO` block from above to express to something like this

```
// (a) Each Component specifies its dependencies as a list (set) of Components. This list is fixed at compile time.
type Dependencies: [Component;]

// For each Dependency, a member of the Component can specify a list of members that it needs. The keys of the returned map are fixed at compile time, but the requested members can always change
fn GetDependencyMembers(&mut self) -> Map<DepType d, List<d::KeyType>>

// Each Component must implement an "update" function which looks like the following.
// "N" varies from component to component.
fn Update<'a>(
    List&'a Dep1Type>,
    ...
    List<&'a DepNType>,
)
```

Unfortunately, my meager rust isn't adequate to translate this into working code. Could someone with more knowledge show me how I should write this?

Comment: uppercase on method name in Rust make me sad.

Comment: If I understood correctly `type Dependencies` does not need to be a "List of types". A "List of types" is just a `struct` if you think about it. Are you sure you need to constrain the `Update` function like this? Why can't it have a signature like `fn Update<'a>(deps: Self::Dependecies<'a>)`.

Comment: I think you want a trait constraint like `type Dependecies<'a>: From<&'a GameContext>`

Comment: `Dependencies` could be a tuple or struct, like `(DependencyOne, DependencyTwo)`. However, to make this useful you'll need another trait you can implement on the tuple/struct to e.g. populate the members from an overall state, for example, because the tuple by itself isn't going to convey any kind of behavior to the system.

Comment: some other thinking, 
1. make list of types into a enum if  list of types are limited and known, then you can pass enum type list.
2. or use `Any` type